# Compound adjective -ed vs. -ing suffix

Tags: adjectives

I find some compound adjectives has a *-ed* suffix, e.g., *red-haired*, *cold-blooded*, *two-faced*, *open-minded*, *light-hearted*, etc.
In comparison, there are also ones with *-ing* suffix, such as *good-looking*, *heart-warming*, *jaw-dropping*, *mouth-watering*, etc.

It appears to me *-ed* suffix is appended to noun, while *-ing* is appended to verb. Can someone corroborate?

Comment: Another way to describe these is that "an adjective has been attached to either a participle or an -ing verb." And you've hit on one important point: you can't make an -ing verb out of a noun! ("hairing"? "blooding"? Though often there *are* corresponding verbs, like "facing.") You don't ask *why* some of these would take the one form or the other; I guess it depends whether we're describing a quality or appearance (she has red hair) or an action or effect (it warms our hearts, it makes our jaws drop).

Comment: (Oops—for many of these the first word is a noun, not an adjective. Aside from "good-looking," most of your other "-ing" examples take the form "X-Ying," and mean "having the effect Y on X." While the "X-Yed" form means "having Y that is X.")

Comment: @AndyBonner Actually, most nouns can be turned into verbs. At least that's what the honchose around here say.

Comment: The ing and ed ones come from this: a warm heart, heart-warming x, open mind, open-minded person. There are tons of adjectives with nouns that can become adjective+verb+ed. And some of the ing ones are in the dictionary (good-looking) while others are not;

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out in comments, the choice between using ***-ed*** or ***-ing*** for derived adjectives depends on whether the relevant word is a noun or a verb.

Sometimes *both* forms can be derived from the same word, depending on whether that word ***is being used as a...***

> noun *([a **po-faced** guard](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/po-faced))*  - his ***face*** looks like a (chamber-pot?)
> OR
> verb *(a [**south-facing**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/south-facing) garden)*  - it ***faces*** southwards

Answer (score 1):

> [1] *red-haired, cold-blooded, two-faced, open-minded, light-hearted, etc.*
>
> [2] *good-looking, heart-warming, jaw-dropping, mouth-watering, etc.*

In [1], the adjectivalisation involves the addition of the *ed* suffix to a nominal consisting of a dependent + a head noun to form a de-phrasal adjective. A very productive construction: all those examples are lexicalised.

In [2] the adjectivalisation has the *ing* suffix attached to a verb to give a verb-centred compound adjective with the active use of a past participle as head and an adjective or noun as first element. All lexicalised.